# MVC ActionLinks render empty when publish to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have encountered a weird issue when I publish my MVC4 application to my web server.

Everything was working fine, and I did change some settings in my routing config.

The issue is that when I run the website on localhost, all of my links render wonderfully.

`@Html.ActionLink("Market Summary","Market","Home")`  Will render as a url.

However, when I upload my project to my server (winhost), anytime I hover over one my links, it simply points to my domain name.  It does this on any page in my project...

I have no clue why this might be occurring since it works fine on localhost.

Here is my routing config.

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Http;
   using System.Web.Mvc;
   using System.Web.Routing;

   namespace ReportGenerator.Web
   {
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{param2}/{param3}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional , param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, param3 = UrlParameter.Optional }

         );


    }
  }
 }
```

Update:  the links are actually rendered blank.  `<a href="">`

Update 2:  if I remove param2 and param2 from the controller, all works as expected... What the HECK!?

Update 3:  Problem solved, very odd issue indeed.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with ASP.NET MVC.

I dug around and found that if you are using an `Html.ActionLink` attribute that the server will often try to fill in any missing parameters, which for some reason results in the url being rendered blank.

I'm not sure the cause of this, and I am sure someone else can provide far more insight.

Basically, you CANNOT have more that one multiple ID in a default route unless every URL contains the parameters.

So what I did was created a SECOND route and made links that worked like this:

```
   @Html.RouteLink(Model.MembershipCount.ToString(), "detailed", new { action="YourActionName", id = "blah", param2 = "foo", param3 = "foo2" }, null) 
   //detailed is where you put whatever you named your route.
```

My routing class now looks like this

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}

        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Detailed",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{param2}/{param3}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "home", id = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, param3 = UrlParameter.Optional }

         );             


    }
}
```

This worked fine, but I am still at a total loss as to why this problem did NOT occur on my development server.  Perhaps Microsoft has patched this insanity and my host just hasn't updated their framework.

I hope this saves someone frustration.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in a ASP .NET MVC 3 app and it was resolved by adding

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

into the `<system.webServer>` section of the web.config file. The app worked fine on the development machine but not the server.